# Kafka brokerlist vs 1 broker while creating a connection?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am running a Kafka cluster.

Sample code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                                      "localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094");     
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
```

- Is mentioning whole broker list is mandatory?
- What will happen, if I provide only `localhost:9092`, Will it always use this particular broker?

  - What if `localhost:9092` broker is down?
- Is the behavior same for consumer API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is mentioning whole broker list is mandatory?

No. The broker list does not have to contain the full set of servers. However, it is recommended to specify multiple ones in case of the server failure.

> What will happen, if I provide only localhost:9092, Will it always use this particular broker?

No. Even only `localhost:9092` is specified as `bootstrap.servers`, the clients will retrieve all broker list by sending Metadata request to that broker. After doing this, **all** brokers can service to the clients.

> What if localhost:9092 broker is down?

That `localhost:9092` is down only affects the partitions on that broker. No impact on the partitions on the rest brokers. However, if the client application was down as well, it could not find the cluster anymore even after it came back, since it failed to connect to the already-down `localhost:9092`. That's why it's recommended for users to provide several brokers instead of just one.

> Is the behavior same for consumer API?

Yes, all above hold true for the consumer as well.